# Linux C console application not using previous command on "keyup"

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I've got the following issue:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    while(1){
        char command[25];
        scanf(" %25[^\n]s", command);
        printf("Command '%s'\n", command); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now whenever I type something in the console it prints me a message with what I just typed.
But if I use the **arrow up key** to get the last command out of the memory, the command being sent is

> ^[[A

Which results in the cursor being moved up by the program.
Now how do I fix this?
I want that the last command from memory is triggered.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually pretty non-trivial thing you are asking for. Luckily, there is a library to fix it: [GNU Readline library](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). Be aware about its licensing, though. Last I heard, it's actual GPL and therefore your own program needs to be that, too, if you use it. NetBSD has a library called [libedit](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/), which seems to claim to do much of the same thing with less restrictive license.

Here are some more help with readline: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/basics-of-using-the-readline-library/

And if you can stomach the idea of not integrating it directly into your own program, there is a handy utility program called [rlwrap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap), which provides the end-user at least some of the goodness transparently.